# Transform to close gap in plane mesh without adding to mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edges

I'm stumped with a problem that seems really basic, but I can't find a solution in the documentation or previous questions, so if someone could help me out, that'd be really great.

I have the plane shape created in the screenshot below, the cut was generated by a boolean operator, and the plane was given a solidfy modifier as well.

I want to close the gap between the two edges selected, without adding to the plane.

The two edges would come together, and close up, but the rest of the plane won't have anything added to it, to compensate for the gaps between the edges closing up, the overall shape would get an incurve so it closes up.

How do I apply a transform etc to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faces are an imaginary geometric abstraction. They can't blend, they always flat. (Technically they are consisted of triangles so that can blend by them, though. But it is not that you are looking for, I suppose) To blend the plane, it should be built from a grid of small faces.

You should subdivide the geometry like this and add an edge using <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Using proportional editing add some initial blend to plane:

[image]

Just a little, to aid physics to detect blend direction:

[image]

Edit radius of proportional editing by scrolling the mouse wheel

Then add cloth physics, disable gravity and enable swearing

[image]

Then run animation playback in object mode to review how plane swears and blends:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer, much appreciated. I have a couple of questions - could you please tell me what the steps are to add initial bend in proportional editing? (I'm very new to blender and don't seem to be doing it properly)

Comment: and should I enable self-collision in the cloth simulation setting as well?